# C# blocking thread cancellation

Tags: c#, task

I am currently developing a service which basically waits for data on a stream. The service can be cancelled at any time, but in most cases it runs for a long period (days). I like to switch my asynchronous design from using `BackgroundWorker` and a loop which checks the current cancellation state of the `BackgroundWorker` and the availability of some data on stream to a much better design using Tasks (as the `BackgroundWorker` is not the best choice for long running threads, as it takes a ThreadPool-Thread).

My current loop / routine looks basically like this:

```
while(!cancelled) {
    CheckIfDataAvailable(); // This check is non-blocking
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

What I basically want to do now is get rid of the `Thread.Sleep()` call, but in the same time the thread should be cancelable in a fair amount of time while also listening if any data is available on a stream (and this operation might block the stream or hinders the check of the cancelation state in some other way).

I know how to cancel a `Task` using a `CancellationToken` but I am not aware of any method combining the cancel-check and the data availability check in a really clean manner (e.g. not using `Thread.Sleep()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g., as follows:

```
async Task BackgroundWord(CancellationToken token)
{
    CheckIfDataAvailable();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x), token);
}
```

If your `CheckIfDataAvailable` method returns a `Task` (that is completed when data is available), you can combine the two as follows:

```
await Task.WhenAny(CheckIfDataAvailable(), Task.Delay(-1, token));
```

`Task.Delay(-1)` will wait forever, so it will only transfer to the completed state if the cancellation token is cancelled. Thus `Task.WhenAny` will wait for either data to become available, or the token to be cancelled.